# Error on Xcode Archive of my Flutter application

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, xcode-archive

For some time now I have had problems when using Archive from Xcode to make the release on the Apple Store of my application developed in Flutter. Specifically, the errors I get are with the schema with Build configuration set to Debug. If I set the schema to Release, the archive is generated without errors, but it is compromised and therefore I cannot release it. The screen below shows the errors I get. Can anyone help me, please? I had this error with url_launcher_ios and SwiftyGif. Very thanks in advance for those who will help me!

[image: error that appears when I try to do Archive with the debug scheme]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit your pod file like below.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
        end
  end
end
```

Comment: When I use this configuration, a new error appears (it seems to be the opposite of the previous one). The error is as follows: 
`ld: '/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ezixgjujohxiescqwducrlosaunh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppAuth/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file '/Users/username/.../Debug-iphoneos/AppAuth/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' for architecture arm64` @darshan-sheta

Comment: replace this config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO' to config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'YES'.

Answer (score 0):

Open ios module with XCode and search for `bitcode` in build settings. Set Enabled to No.

This worked for me instead of trying to do this inside Podfile.